# Use more than one directive to add data attributes to components

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils

I have two directives which are supposed to add data attributes to components for testing, however, only one of the directives actually gets added. The two components are Bootstrap-Vue's BFormInput and BButton.

I tried removing everything but one of the buttons and the directive is still not added i.e

```
    <b-input-group class="sm-2 mb-2 mt-2">
        <b-button
          variant="primary"
          @click="searchJobs"
          class="rounded-0"
          v-jobs-search-button-directive="{ id: 'search-button' }"
        >
          Search
        </b-button>
    </b-input-group>
```

wrapper.html() output is:

```
    <b-input-group-stub tag="div" class="sm-2 mb-2 mt-2"><b-button-stub target="_self" event="click" routertag="a" variant="secondary" type="button" tag="button" class="rounded-0">
            Search
          </b-button-stub></b-input-group-stub>
```

However, it is added when instead of a button I leave in place the input form i.e.

```
<b-input-group class="sm-2 mb-2 mt-2">
        <b-form-input
          v-jobs-search-input-directive="{ id: 'input-keyword' }"
          class="mr-2 rounded-0"
          placeholder="Enter Search term..."
          :value="this.searchConfig.Keyword"
          @input="this.updateJobsSearchConfig"
        />
    </b-input-group>
```

wrapper.html() output is:

```
<b-input-group-stub tag="div" class="sm-2 mb-2 mt-2"><b-form-input-stub value="" placeholder="Enter Search term..." type="text" class="mr-2 rounded-0" data-jobs-search-input-id="input-keyword"></b-form-input>
```

This is how I add the directives

```
<template>
<b-input-group class="sm-2 mb-2 mt-2">
        <b-form-input
          v-jobs-search-input-directive="{ id: 'input-keyword' }"
          class="mr-2 rounded-0"
          placeholder="Enter Search term..."
          :value="this.searchConfig.Keyword"
          @input="this.updateJobsSearchConfig"
        />
        <b-button
          variant="primary"
          @click="searchJobs"
          class="rounded-0"
          v-jobs-search-button-directive="{ id: 'search-button' }"
        >
          Search
</b-button>
</b-input-group>
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions, mapState } from 'vuex'
import JobService from '@/api-services/job.service'
import JobsSearchInputDirective from '@/directives/components/jobs/JobsSearchInputDirective'
import JobsSearchButtonDirective from '@/directives/components/jobs/JobsSearchButtonDirective'

export default {
  name: 'jobs-search',
  directives: { JobsSearchInputDirective, JobsSearchButtonDirective },
  data () {
    return {
      jobs: [],
      pages: 0
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      pagedConfig: state => state.jobs.paged,
      searchConfig: state => state.jobs.search
    })
  },
  methods: {
   // Methods go here
}
}
```

jobs-search-input-directive is

```
export default (el, binding) => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
    Object.keys(binding.value).forEach(value => {
      el.setAttribute(`data-jobs-search-input-${value}`, binding.value[value])
    })
  }
}
```

jobs-search-button-directive is

```
export default (el, binding) => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
    Object.keys(binding.value).forEach(value => {
      el.setAttribute(`data-jobs-search-button-${value}`, binding.value[value])
    })
  }
}
```

This is the test I run, mounting with `shallowMount`

```
  it('should call jobsSearch method on search button click event', () => {
    wrapper.find('[data-jobs-search-button-id="search-button"]').trigger('click')
    expect(searchJobs).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
```

which comes back with

```
Error: [vue-test-utils]: find did not return [data-jobs-search-button-id="search-button"], cannot call trigger() on empty Wrapper
```

However `wrapper.find('[data-jobs-search-input-id="input-keyword"]')` DOES find the input-form

The two directives are registered in the `JobsSearch.vue` component and they definitely get rendered if I remove the `process.env` part

I expect the attribute to be added to both components but it only gets added to the BFormInput when testing. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is `v-jobs-search-button-directive`? Is that something you've written? Can we see the code for it? Have you definitely registered that directive correctly? Any errors in the console? Does the directive fail in the application itself or just when running the tests?

Comment: @skirtle I've added the code of the directives above. They are registered on the component inside directives: {...}. They don't fail in the application itself but only when running the tests. More specifically, only ``` v-jobs-search-input-directive``` gets added for testing, whereas ```v-jobs-search-button-directive``` doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the problem occurs when...

- ... trying to use a directive...
- ... on a functional child component...
- ... with `shallowMount`.

`b-button` is a functional component.

I've put together the demo below to illustrate the problem. It mounts the same component in 3 different ways and it only fails in the specific case outlined above.

```js
MyComponent = {
  template: `
    <div>
      <my-normal v-my-directive></my-normal>
      <my-functional v-my-directive></my-functional>
    </div>
  `,

  components: {
    MyNormal: {
      render: h => h('span', 'Normal')
    },
    
    MyFunctional: {
      functional: true,
      render: (h, context) => h('span', context.data, 'Functional')
    }
  },
  
  directives: {
    myDirective (el) {
      el.setAttribute('name', 'Lisa')
    }
  }
}

const v = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  components: {
    MyComponent
  }
})

document.getElementById('markup1').innerText = v.$el.innerHTML

const cmp1 = VueTestUtils.mount(MyComponent)

document.getElementById('markup2').innerText = cmp1.html()

const cmp2 = VueTestUtils.shallowMount(MyComponent)

document.getElementById('markup3').innerText = cmp2.html()
```

```css
#markup1, #markup2, #markup3 {
  border: 1px solid #777;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-template-compiler@2.6.10/browser.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@vue/test-utils@1.0.0-beta.29/dist/vue-test-utils.iife.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <my-component></my-component>
</div>
<div id="markup1"></div>
<div id="markup2"></div>
<div id="markup3"></div>
```

I haven't really looked at the code for `vue-test-utils` before but stepping through in the debugger makes me suspicious of this line:

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/blob/9dc90a3fd4818ff70e270568a2294b1d8aa2c3af/packages/create-instance/create-component-stubs.js#L99

This is the `render` function for the stubbed child component. It would appear that `context.data.directives` does contain the correct directive but they aren't being passed on in the call to `h`.

Contrast that with the `render` function in my example component `MyFunctional`, which passes on all of `data`. That's required for directives to work with a functional component but when `MyFunctional` gets replaced with a stub the new `render` function seems to drop the `directives` property.

The only workaround I've been able to come up with is to provide your own stub:

```js
VueTestUtils.shallowMount(MyComponent, {
  stubs: {
    BButton: { render: h => h('div')}
  }
})
```

By using a non-functional stub the directive works fine. Not sure how much value this would take away from the test though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think we will end up using classes instead of directives since it looks like most of Bootstrap-vue's components are functional.