# Testing for a function/method call on click event inside a functional component

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, vue-test-utils

After a number of days hitting a wall, I understood that testing functional components with vue-test-utils causes some issues

To summarize, I am using Bootstrap-Vue's `B-Button` with a `@click` event on it that calls some function/method. When I try to run a test to understand whether the method is called, the test fails. However, when I swap the functional `B-Button`with a `<button>` the test passes.

Here is `JobSearch.vue` component

```
<template>
  <b-input-group>
    <b-form-input
      class="mr-2 rounded-0"
      placeholder="Enter Search term..."
      id="input-keyword"
    />
<!--    <b-button-->
<!--      @click="searchJobs"-->
<!--      class="rounded-0 ml-2"-->
<!--      variant="primary"-->
<!--      id="reset-button"-->
<!--    >-->
<!--      Reset-->
<!--    </b-button>-->

    <button
      @click="resetFilter"
      class="rounded-0 ml-2"
      id="reset-button">
      Reset
    </button>
  </b-input-group>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'job-search-test',
  methods: {
    async searchJobs () {
      console.log('Calling Search Jobs from JobsSearchTest')
    },
    resetFilter () {
      console.log('Clicked On Reset')
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    // this.searchJobs()
  }
}
</script>
```

Here is `JobSearch.spec.js`

```
import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
import JobSearchTest from '@/components/jobs/JobSearchTest'

const localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.use(BootstrapVue)

describe('JobsSearchTest.vue', () => {
  it('should call searchJobs method when component is mounted', () => {
    let searchJobs = jest.fn()

    shallowMount(JobSearchTest, {
      methods: {
        searchJobs
      },
      localVue })
    expect(searchJobs).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
  })

  it('should call resetFilter method on reset button click event', () => {
    let resetFilter = jest.fn()
    const wrapper = shallowMount(JobSearchTest, {
      methods: {
        resetFilter
      },
      localVue
    })
    expect(resetFilter).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
    wrapper.find('#reset-button').trigger('click')
    console.log(wrapper.find('#reset-button'))
    expect(resetFilter).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
})
```

By commenting out the `<b-button>` part and commenting the `<button>` the test fails, however, it will be nice if it can pass since for this project we would like to use Bootstrap Vue.

Any ideas for a work around, which would not take away the value of the test? For example, according to an earlier question I asked, functional components don't operate well with directives, hence by using a non-functional stub the directive works fine, however, this takes away the value of the test.

[Use more than one directive to add data attributes to components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57808229/use-more-than-one-directive-to-add-data-attributes-to-components)

Comment: Have you tried to wrap the b-button with the <b-button-group> tag?

Comment: @Skyentao I haven't tried this in particular but I tried stubbing the ```b-button``` inside ```shallowMount``` which worked. However, I then spoke with someone on Vue Land Discord channel and he advised to not use shallowMount. Shallow mount is really only good when you are testing a component and not any children... and since b-button is a child component... I need to bring it in

Comment: You can start using the boostrap-vue boilerplate for this case
https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/button-group/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understood there are two answers to this.

When using `shallowMount` the functional components should be stubbed when creating the wrapper.

The other solution is to use `mount`. Shallow mount is really only good when only the component is tested in isolation. Here I am testing children... and since b-button is a child component... I need to bring it in